# Palindrome - C language only

Tags: c, string, palindrome

I was wondering why the result is not correct.
If I type string to test whether the string is palindrome or not,
the results are all same whenever I try.

For example, if I type 'dad' to test, this shows me it is not palindrome.
However, if I type 'god', it still shows me that this is not palindrome.

I have a no idea how can I fix this in right way...
Please let me know how can I make it.

Thank you.

(codes below)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void isPalindrome(char *str, int n);

int main() {
    char str[100];
    int n = strlen(str);
    char choice;
    printf("Will you run this program? : ");
    scanf("%c", &choice);
    getchar();

    while (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y') {
        isPalindrome(str, n);
        printf("Retry? : ");
        scanf("%c", &choice);
        getchar();
    }
}

void isPalindrome(char *str, int n) {
    int flag = 1;
    printf("Type strings : ");
    gets_s(str, 100);

    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) { 
        if ('A' <= str[i] && str[i] <= 'Z') {
            str[i] = str[i] - 'A' + 'a';
        }

        if (strlen(str) / 2 == 0) {
            if (str[i] != str[n - i - 1]) {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        } else
        if (strlen(str) / 2 != 0) {
            if (str[i] != str[n - i]) {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1) {
        printf("%s is a palindrome \n", str);
    } else {
        printf("%s is not a palindrome \n", str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now is a good time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: `(strlen(str) / 2 == 0)` makes no sense. perhaps you meant `(strlen(str) %% 2 == 0)` ?

Comment: "*Will you run this program?*" -- but ... but ... didn't I do that already?

Comment: does this work when you give it the string `b` ? does it print `b is a palindrome` ? if yes, then i probably caught your bug in my previous comment.

Comment: `int n = strlen(str);` : `str` is uninitialized.

Comment: `str` in `main()` is an uninitialised array.   Calling `strlen(str)` therefore has undefined behaviour.   And that happens before the first `printf()`, and before calling `IsPalindrome()`.

Comment: Why check the string length every time you check a character... the string length never changes right?

Comment: @HyeongCheol  Do you consider a string like this "a1A" as a palindrome?

Comment: @HyeongCheol  Why is there  printf("Type strings : "); instead of printf( "Type a string: " );?

Answer (score 3):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters  shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The function `isPalindrome` should do only one thing - to check whether a supplied string is a palindrome. All inputs should be done in main.

Moreover as the function does not change the string itself its corresponding parameter should be declared with the qualifier `const`.

The function should have the return type `int` or `_Bool`.

This second statement in main

```
char str[100];
int n = strlen(str);
```

does not make sense because the array `str` contains neither string. Moreover the type of the variable `n` should be `size_T` because it is the return type of the function `strlen`.

Instead of these manipulations

```
    if ('A' <= str[i] && str[i] <= 'Z')
    {
        str[i] = str[i] - 'A' + 'a';
    }
```

it is much better to use standard function `tolower`, And you have to convert two symbols of the string simultaneously.

The program can look the following way.

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__  1

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 100

int isPalindrome(const char s[], size_t n)
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while (i < n / 2 &&
        tolower((unsigned char)s[i]) == tolower((unsigned char)s[n - i - 1])) ++i;

    return i == n / 2;
}

int main( void )
{
    char choice;

    printf( "Will you run this program? : " );
    scanf( " %c", &choice );
    getchar();

    while ( choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y' )
    {
        char s[N];

        printf( "Type a string : " );
        gets_s( s, N );

        if ( isPalindrome( s, strlen( s ) ) )
        {
            printf( "\"%s\" is a palindrome\n", s );
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\"%s\" is not a palindrome\n", s);
        }

        printf( "Retry? : " );
        scanf( " %c", &choice );
        getchar();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Will you run this program? : y
Type a string : dad
"dad" is a palindrome
Retry? : y
Type a string : god
"god" is not a palindrome
Retry? : n
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example implementation you can use that includes good practices in C programming, and is also case-insensitive using the built-in function [`tolower()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_tolower.htm):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLRTsIwFH3vV1xnTDYB47tCIj755rsQ03YdXCwt6TqJmn37vB2bFghwH5rmnHPP7T2bHC2kbJprNFJXuYLH0udo75YTFkMOzeIQy4W1eh@U/mujAsQCB1i@co0md3atUrnk7nYIJX6rd589sE@LOWzI2L8cyYhmRMCao0kz@GFAdaxNuBA8IfFpWsoLkulUPgvxdEayUOqjPMMHquWc8pUzcP/A6pMBgKiKPgTQyvTLdQjCOPRHyIoQ0u2wYAE8uotu9HaJWkG6gglgbxmKU7e32m6VS2nyGw4G826TUOKAHo1W836bUFhAyuFqDCI2jXYtuC7Vv1/Ndmcch3eVahM598GBfrF@RBi6FxxxwyCgGMI9y@LHtIZFmtyUlDbtu/nrm7mZSdrGbuMaFL32ZK@x/kI/q5vmFw)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool isPalindrome(char*, size_t);
void printIsPalindrome(char*);

int main() {
    printIsPalindrome("abba");
    printIsPalindrome("abbccbba");
    printIsPalindrome("aBBcCbbA");
    printIsPalindrome("geeks");
    printIsPalindrome("");

    return 0;
}

bool isPalindrome(char* buf, size_t len) {
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = len;
    char a;
    char b;

    while (j > i) {
        a = tolower(buf[i++]);
        b = tolower(buf[--j]);

        if (a != b) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

void printIsPalindrome(char* str) {
    if (isPalindrome(str, strlen(str))) {
        printf("%s is a palindrome\r\n", str);
    } else {
        printf("%s is not a palindrome\r\n", str);
    }
}
```

Essentially, you want to separate your driving logic from the implementation checking whether the string is a palindrome or not. This is why the function is split into `isPalindrome()` and `printIsPalindrome()`.

A function checking whether a condition is true or not should not have the side-effect of outputting to the console, this is a good practice in general and not just in C.

A generic function that is expected to be re-used (i.e. `isPalindrome()`) should also not assume that the passed buffer (the `char* buf`) is a C string, so checking `strlen()` should only be done in driver code, `printIsPalindrome()`, not portable logic. The reason for this is to avoid security vulnerabilities via buffer overflow attacks, if other people intend to use your implementation of `isPalindrome()` in their program as a dependency, hypothetically. It allows them to specify the size of the buffer they pass explicitly, so it is on them to verify that the buffer is not accessed beyond the allocated chunk of memory.

Lastly, anything that checks in the index of a buffer (`i` and `j`) should be `size_t` in order to be portable code, as `size_t` is guaranteed to be large enough to address all memory space, while `int` does not hold that guarantee.

Comment: `isPalindrome` has undefined behavior for the empty string.